# What does label function do in R?

Tags: r

I am doing clustering in r.
There is a question in my exercise: *Randomly assign a cluster label to each observation*
I have made a combined matrix for `x1` and `x2`. In the solution the next thing given is the code below.

```
labels = sample(2, nrow(x), replace = T)
labels
```

What is this line doing?

Comment: You are using the `sample` function not `labels`. `labels` is actually the object containing the outcome of the `sample` function. Have a look to [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/sample) and you will understand what this function does.

Comment: Simply put: you're randomly sampling 2 rows from all rows of `x` with replacement and storing those two rows in `labels`, the second `labels` line prints out the result